Determine the number of admissible polygons as a function of $m$.
This is a modified version of problem 9.109 from A path to combinatorics for undergraduates.
Let $m$ be a positive integer. In the coordinate plane, we call polygon $A_1A_2...A_n$ admissible if
(i) its perimeter $A_1A_2+A_2A_3+\cdots+A_nA_1$ is equal to m;
(ii) for $1\le i \le n$, $A_i=(x_i,y_i)$ is lattice point;
(iii) $x_1\le x_2\le \cdots \le x_n$
(iv) $y_1=y_n=0$, and there is a $k$ with $1\lt k\lt m$ such that $y_1\le y_2\le \cdots \le y_k$ and $y_k\ge y_{k+1}\ge \cdots \ge y_n$
(v) $x_1=0$
(vi) Polygon $A_1A_2...A_n$ is not degenerate. (no angles of $180°$, no angles of $0°$, no sides of length $0$)
(vii) Each side of polygon $A_1A_2...A_n$ is either horizontal or vertical.
Determine the number of admissible polygons as a function of $m$.
(Two different admissible polygons are considered distinct even if one can be obtained from the other via composition of reflections and rotations.)
(v) was not required by the problem originally, but I decided to add the condition so that two admissible polygons are considered identical if one can be obtained from the other via translation. Otherwise, we could just translate an admissible polygons to the right infinitely many times obtain infinitely many different admissible polygons.
(vi) and (vii) were added to make the problem simpler. I believe the author of the book had intended to add them but didn't. Without those $2$ conditions, I think the problem would be too difficult to anyone who restricts themself to using combinatorics tools or arguments only from that book.
It was remarked that there were two solutions to the problem.
The following $2$ conjectures were inspired by @Christopher Wells comment.
Conjecture $1$: Let $f(m)$ be the number of admissible polygon. We have
$f(m)=\begin{cases} F_{m-3} &\text{if m is even and } m\ge 4\\
0 &\text{if m is odd or }m\le 3
\end{cases}$
where $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number.
Conjecture $2$: For even $m$ and $0\le j\le \frac{m}{2}-2$, define $P_{m,j}$ to be the set of all polygon satisfying conditions (i)-(vii) and the condition that $(x_n,y_n)=(j+1,0)$. Then $|P_{m,j}|=\binom{m-4-j}{j}$.
If conjecture $2$ holds, then we may prove conjecture $1$ by the following:
Let $m\le3$. Assume $f(m)\neq0$. Let $Y=A_1A_2...A_n$ be a polygon satisfying (i)-(vii). Note that $Y$ must have one horizontal side on the $x$-axis, one horizontal side above the $x$-axis, one vertical side on the $y$-axis, one horizontal side to the right of the $y$-axis. It follows that the perimeter of $Y$ is at least $4$, a contradiction.
Let $m$ be odd and $m\ge4$. Assume $f(m)\neq0$. Let $X=A_1A_2...A_n$ be a polygon satisfying (i)-(vii). Note that for any horizontal side of $X$ above the $x$-axis, there exists exactly one side of $X$ on the $x$-axis. Also note that for any vertical side of $X$ to the right of the $y$-axis, there exists exactly one side of $X$ on the $y$-axis. So the perimeter of $X$ must be even, a contradiction.
Let $m$ be even and $m\ge4$. Then we have
$$\begin{align}
f(m)&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{m}{2}-2}|P_{m,j}|\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{m}{2}-2}\binom{m-4-j}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{m-3-1}{2}}\binom{m-3-j-1}{j}\\
&=F_{m-3}\\
\end{align}$$
I have verified conjectures $2$ for $m$ up to $12$. But I can't prove it for all $m$.

Have you calculated the number for a few small values of $m$?

You rightly added the necessary condition (which the author has missed) in terms of translation. We could make that condition with $x_1=0$ which will match the text. Simpler way is $A_1=(0,0)$ here.

I think for $m=1$ and $m=2$, the number of such polygons is $0$. But for $m\ge 3$, things get very complicated for me since the length may not necessarily be integers so I don't know how to calculate the number of admissible polygons for those values.

@Prem but that would imply, by condition (iii), that all the $x_j$ are 0

I have updated my comment , @19021605 , I think it is okay now.

Can polygons have redundant vertices? Starting with the triangle (0,0), (3,4), (3,0), can we turn it into a pentagon by adding (2,0) and (1,0) even though they don't change the shape (and so they don't change the perimeter)?
... Actually, it's not even stated explicitly that $A_i \neq A_{i+1}$, but I feel confident that it should be assumed.

@ChristopherWells in your example, I don't get which vertex correspond to which coordinates. And I think $A_i\neq A_{i+1}$ already follows from the definition of polygon. If not, then yes, it should be assumed, otherwise we could just add as finitely many points we want in one of the vertex, say the origin, and get infinitely many different admissible polygons of equal perimeter.

Bad example, I forgot the rule that the x-coordinate should be increasing. Let's say instead $A_0 = (0,0), A_1=(0,1), A_2=(0,2), A_3=(0,3), A_4=(4,0)$. This has the same shape as the triangle $A_0 = (0,0), A_1=(0,3), A_2=(4,0)$; we can often add extra vertices that have interior angles of 180°. Is this a different polygon?

Yes, since the two polygons have different number of vertices.

If diagonal sides are allowed (e.g. $(0,0)$, $(3,4)$, $(6,0)$ with perimeter $5+5+6=16$) then I would think that things get very tricky as Pythagorean triples get involved.

They are allowed.

If anyone else is curious about the reference to "two solutions to this problem", the original source says: "(This problem is due to David Vincent, who studied this topic
at the Clay Mathematics Spring Program in March 2003. Tiankai
Liu and David developed two wonderful solutions on the PEA
math team's bus trip to the ARML meet, May 31, 2003.)" It is not meant to imply that the solution isn't unique, just that there are multiple proofs of it.

I had a look at the source material to see if maybe it was clearer, but none of this seems to be explained there either. I'm also curious if we're allowed degenerate polygons, such as $(0,0), (1,0), (1,1), (2,1), (2,0)$ where some of the sides coincide partially. Or even cases like $(0,0), (0,1), (0,0), (2,0)$ where some non-consecutive vertices coincide. I'd want to allow them, but then on what grounds do we exclude sides of length zero (which, as you pointed out above, makes for an infinite number of solutions)?

@ChristopherWells Assuming the coordinates correspond to the vertex in the same order as listed, the $2^{nd}$ example violate (iii).  As for the first example, we would have $A_1A_2=1, A_2A_3=1, A_3A_4=1, A_4,A_5=1, A_5A_1=2$, so the perimeter is $6$.

For the second example, $x_1=0, x_2=0, x_3=0$, and $x_4=2$, so we do have $x_1 \leq x_2 \leq x_3 \leq x_4$.

... anyway, I tried out the first few values. Excluding all forms of degenerate polygons (no angles of 180°, no angles of 0°, no sides of length 0) and excluding diagonal sides, I can find 1 solution for m=4, 2 for m=6, 5 for m=8, 13 for m=10, and 34 for m=12. Odd values of m are impossible. This looks like every other element of the Fibonacci series... maybe that's what the problem was supposed to be?

@ChristopherWells Ok I guess we could allow non-consecutive vertices coincide.

@ChristopherWells I think there's a chance that the problem was supposed to be like that. Else things just get very very complicated (since the lengths are not necessarily integers or even rational) and I don't think any of the previous worked examples in that book even come close to being that complicated.

This is an alternative solution.
Let $m\le3$. Assume $f(m)\neq0$. Let $Y=A_1A_2...A_n$ be a polygon satisfying (i)-(vii). Note that $Y$ must have one horizontal side on the $x$-axis, one horizontal side above the $x$-axis, one vertical side on the $y$-axis, one horizontal side to the right of the $y$-axis. It follows that the perimeter of $Y$ is at least $4$, a contradiction.
Let $m$ be odd and $m\ge4$. Assume $f(m)\neq0$. Let $X=A_1A_2...A_n$ be a polygon satisfying (i)-(vii). Note that for any horizontal side of $X$ above the $x$-axis, there exists exactly one side of $X$ on the $x$-axis. Also note that for any vertical side of $X$ to the right of the $y$-axis, there exists exactly one side of $X$ on the $y$-axis. So the perimeter of $X$ must be even, a contradiction.
For even $m$ and $0\le j\le \frac{m}{2}-2$, define $P_{m,j}$ to be the set of all polygon satisfying conditions (i)-(vii) and the condition that $(x_n,y_n)=(j+1,0)$.
Let $Z=A_1A_2...A_n\in P_{m,j}$. By (iv), (vi) and (vii), there exists a $k$ such that $y_1\le y_2\le \cdots \le y_k$ and $y_k=y_{k+1}\ge \cdots \ge y_n$. Reflect each side of $Z$ that are to the right of the line $x=x_k$ about the line $y=y_k$. Remove the sides $A_1A_2, A_kA_{k+1},$ and the image of $A_{n-1}A_n$.  This creates $2$ paths consisting of only upsteps and rightsteps, one starting from $(0,1)$ and ending in $(x_k,y_k)$ and another starting in $(x_{k+1},y_{k+1})$ and ending in $(x_n,2y_k-1)$. Call the former $P$ and the latter $Q$. Translate both $P$ and $Q$ downwards by one unit to form $P'$ and $Q'$. Translate $Q'$ to the left by one unit to form $Q''$. Note that $P'$ and $Q''$ are connected. So we have a path $T$ starting from $(0,0)$ and ending in $(x_n-1,2y_k-2)$. Since $Z\in P_{m,j}$ and the height of $Z$ is $\frac{m-2(j+1)}{2}$, $T$ ends in $(j,m-2j-4)$. This establishes a one-to-one correspondence between $P_{m,j}$ and the set of paths consisting of upsteps and rightsteps starting from $(0,0)$ and ending in $(j,m-2j-4)$. The number of such paths is $\binom{m-j-4}{j}$.
Therefore $$\begin{align}
f(m)&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{m}{2}-2}|P_{m,j}|\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{m}{2}-2}\binom{m-4-j}{j}\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^{\frac{m-3-1}{2}}\binom{m-3-j-1}{j}\\
&=F_{m-3}\\
\end{align}$$
To summarize, we have
$f(m)=\begin{cases} F_{m-3} &\text{if m is even and } m\ge 4\\
0 &\text{if m is odd or }m\le 3
\end{cases}$

For odd $m$, there are none. For even $m$, there's solutions equal to the $(m-3)$th element of the Fibonacci sequence.
As discussed in the comments, the problem is a little unclear - it doesn't define what a "polygon" is, such as whether we can have edges that overlap, and seems to allow sloped edges as long as their lengths are integers. All that seems a bit hard to keep track for an undergraduate combinatorics exercise!
For this answer I'll assume that all edges are horizontal or vertical, and corners of 0° or 180° aren't allowed - so, effectively, all corners have to be inner or outer right angles.

Then the only admissible polygons are "bar charts" like this one:

Let's call its maximum width $w$.
It should rise up to $k$ and then fall back down. A neat combinatorial trick to deal with this is to flip the right half about the line $y=k$, so that we get a curve which is monotonic all the way along. Like this:

This creates a one-to-one mapping between the bar charts of length $w$ and height $k$, and the paths going only up and to the right from $(0,0)$ to $(w-1, 2k)$.
Note that since the maximum $k$ is actually attained, the bar chart must have at least one column at height $k$, but this is not required by the path. The fix is simple: remove one column of height $k$ from the path. Bar charts with $x$ columns at height $k$ map to paths with $x-1$ steps right at height $k$, for all $x \geq 1$.

Onto the perimeter. The perimeter of the bar chart $m$ is given by $m = 2w + 2k$, since there are $w$ steps left and $w$ steps right and $k$ steps up and $k$ steps down. We can also write this as $2k=m - 2w$.
So for even $m$, the number of bar charts of perimeter $m$ is the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to any point on the line $y = m-2-2x$. Let's call this line $\mathcal L_m$. How can we calculate the number of such paths?
(By the way, the perimeter of the bar chart is obviously even, so there are no solutions for odd $m$. But we might as well allow the line $\mathcal L_m$ to be defined for odd $m$.)

The last step must have been either a step up, in which case the previous position must have had a $y$-coordinate 1 lower, i.e. it was on the line $y+1 = m-2-2x$, which is $y = (m-1)-2-2x$, the line $\mathcal L_{m-1}$. Or it was a step right, so the previous position had $x$-coordinate 1 lower, and it was on the line $y = (m-2)-2-2x$ which is $\mathcal L_{m-2}$. So the number of paths  for some value of $m$ is equal to the number for $m-1$ plus the number for $m-2$. This is the recurrence relation defining the Fibonacci numbers!
And it is easy to see that there is one such path for $m=4$ (and $\mathcal F_{1}=1$ ) and one for $m=5$ (and $\mathcal F_{2}=1$), so the rest are given by the $(m-3)$th element of the Fibonacci sequence. And for even $m$, this is the number of admissible polygons.

Regarding the line "one-to-one mapping between the bar charts of length $w$ and height $k$ ,and the paths going only up and to the right from $(0,0)$
to $(w−1,2k)$." Do the paths also satisfy the requirement that each path ends with an upstep?

Er... whoops. You should remove the last upstep, then. Make the path end at (w-1, 2k-1). I had some notes on the case where the polygon is allowed to have angles of size 0, I must have got then mixed up.

Ok. If you don't mind, could you edit that info into your answer.

Another thing that I just realized is that each path should start with an upstep.
